# How custom hooks are updated?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm generating two dropdown components using a custom hook `useDropdown()`, one for an animal and the other one for the breeds.

I'm confused about how the second dropdown `<BreedDropdown/>` is updated with the new breeds as the animal changes. In other words who is the responsible for calling the custom hook again so that the new dropdown be returned?

```
const [breeds, setBreeds] = useState([]);
const [animal, AnimalDropdown] = useDropdown("Animal", "dog", ANIMALS);
const [breed, BreedDropdown, setBreed] = useDropdown("Breed", "", breeds);

useEffect(() => {
  setBreeds([]);
  setBreed("");

  pet.breeds(animal).then(({ breeds }) => {
    const breedStrings = breeds.map(({ name }) => name);
    setBreeds(breedStrings);
  }, console.error);
}, [animal, setBreeds, setBreed]);
return (
  <div className="search-params">
    <h1>{animal}</h1>
    <form action="">
      <AnimalDropdown />
      <BreedDropdown />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
);
```

Edit: the implementation for the custom hook.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const useDropdown = (label, defaultState, options) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(defaultState);
  const id = `use-dropdown-${label.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase()}`;
  const Dropdown = () => (
    <label htmlFor={id}>
      {label}
      <select
        id={id}
        value={state}
        onChange={e => setState(e.target.value)}
        onBlur={e => setState(e.target.value)}
        disabled={options.length === 0}
      >
        <option>All</option>
        {options.map(item => (
          <option key={item} value={item}>
            {item}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </label>
  );
  return [state, Dropdown, setState];
};

export default useDropdown;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm confused about how the second dropdown  is updated with the new breeds as the animal changes.

While we can't know how the custom hook `useDropdown` implemented, from your code it happens due to `useEffect` hook, you call `setBreed` in the callback function on `animal` change:

```
useEffect(() => {
  ...
  setBreed('');

  ...
}, [animal, setBreeds, setBreed]);
```

> Who is responsible for calling the custom hook again so that the new dropdown be returned?

It depends on the custom hook implementation.

Comment: I will provide the implementation for the custom hook.

Comment: Custom hook is just a normal function that uses hooks, extracting the logic to the main component will give the same effect, so what answer do you expect in asking “who”?

Comment: when `animal` changes we invoke `useEffect()` to  clear the `breeds` and `breed` then calls the api for fetching the new breeds for that animal , after that how BreedDropdown get's updated wit what recently returned by the API?

Comment: Then in fetch you calling again setBreeds which causes render and again calling your custom hook with the updated options